# getting wrong dates from a feather file via pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, feather

A feather file generated by R, has a start_time column that contains both date and time. The date is from year 2016.

I am reading the same file in pandas using below code

```
df = feather.read_dataframe(file)
```

When I am displaying the df, it shows the date of year 1970. The date is of type datetime64[ns, UTC]. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In last version of pandas (0.20.1) you can use [`read_feather`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_feather.html):

```
result = pd.read_feather('example.feather')
```

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-feather).